# error "mutate()`: ! Problem while computing. invalid version specification"

Tags: r, tidyverse, error-code

I was running the following piece of code that was working fine:

```
df_New <- df %>% 
+     mutate(column1 = map(column1, ~ py_eval(.x) %>% 
+                                        bind_rows))  %>% 
+     unnest(column1)
```

however when returning at a later date I received this error when trying to re-run the code:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `column1 = map(column1,
  ~py_eval(.x) %>% bind_rows)`.
Caused by error:
! invalid version specification ‘'\\.\tm1174\w2k'’, ‘..EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.’, ‘. paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.’
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Problem while computing `column1 = map(column1, ~py_eval(.x) %>% bind_rows)`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have no Idea what has changed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you provide example data for df?